# Execute action in Gradle after all plugins applied, but before "afterEvaluate()"

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

I try to configure my project from a custom plugin. I want to set a default URL and credentials for the publishing extension if plugin `maven-publish` is applied. I need know whether the plugin is applied or not.

In a function of my custom plugin I want to write something like this (not actual code)

```
project.afterPluginApply {
  if (project.pluginc.any("maven-publish")) {
    setDefaultUrl()
  }
}
```

**I don't want use**  `project.pluginManager.withPlugin("maven-publish")`
because I want see all applied plugins for the project (I want to configure many extensions and some value may change if whether or not other plugins are applied).

**I don't want use** `subProject.afterEvaluate {}` because, if I configured a field in `build.gradle.kts` I would overwrite it with my plugin.

I could write some dirty code like this

```
(it.pluginManager as DefaultPluginManager).idMappings[DefaultPluginId.unvalidated("maven-publish")] != null
```

But I'd rather like to find a better solution.